# Eclipse console input

Tags: java, eclipse, input, console

So, I'm doing a programme in eclipse, and every time I run main method I have to input bunch of lines (variables) in console. Is there a way to input just once and copy it to notepad or word and copy inputs back to console when I do next run?

Comment: sure, you can either set them in the arguments by changing the configuration if eclipse allows or you can create a text file and load all input by reading the file from your code.

Comment: For testing, wouldn't it be as easy to programmatically input the data inside your program rather than automate the process from another app?

Comment: hardcoding will also work for testing the code!!